# Override copy to clipboard function in AG Grid in order to format data

Tags: excel, copy, ag-grid, paste

Assuming a multi-headers grid like this one:

[image]

The right-click option 'Copy to clipboard with headers' cannot copy multi-lines headers. In this example, it will only copy 'Name', 'Country', 'Skills' and 'Proficiency'.
I want to override this function to implement multi-lines headers.

I'd like to have possibility to merge cells and put color on these cells too. How can this be implemented, because it is raw data in clipboard ?

I know some grid options like processHeaderForClipboard. I can put a carriage return between headers, but since the function is called at each column, the carriage return will be applied on the first column each time.

Is there some workaround or do you have some clues ? Thanks

Comment: Are you able to find a solution  work around for this?